# Click on table row if text String is found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I have this Angular component implemented as a table:

```
<div _ngcontent-nyg-c4="" fxlayout="column" class="feature-content" id="content.rowify" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: stretch space-between; align-items: stretch; max-width: 100%;"><mobileweb-value-display _ngcontent-nyg-c34="" class="compact-xs" id="materialInquiryDuplicateMessage" label.flex="100%" _nghost-nyg-c31=""><!----><div _ngcontent-nyg-c31="" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="start stretch" class="compact-xs track-size-dialog-c3ba10e1-f724-345e-d637-788428718b44" id="materialInquiryDuplicateMessage.form-info" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: stretch flex-start; align-items: stretch; max-height: 100%;"><!----><!----><mat-label _ngcontent-nyg-c31="" class="compact-xs compact-right-margin ng-star-inserted" id="materialInquiryDuplicateMessage.label" style="flex: 1 1 100%; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%;">Please select one material from the list<!----><span _ngcontent-nyg-c31="" class="ng-star-inserted">:</span></mat-label><!----><div _ngcontent-nyg-c31="" fxflex="auto" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="space-between stretch" class="ng-star-inserted" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: stretch space-between; align-items: stretch; flex: 1 1 auto;"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div></mobileweb-value-display><div _ngcontent-nyg-c34="" id="table-container" class="resizeable-container-c3ba10e1-f724-345e-d637-788428718b44" style="height: calc(100vh - 97px);"><mobileweb-mobile-grid _ngcontent-nyg-c34=""><!----><ag-grid-angular class="mobile-grid mobile-grid-top-gap"><div ref="eRootWrapper" class="ag-root-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-ltr ag-keyboard-focus">
                
                <div class="ag-root-wrapper-body ag-layout-normal ag-focus-managed" ref="rootWrapperBody"><div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-top" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <!--AG-GRID-COMP--><div class="ag-root ag-unselectable ag-layout-normal" role="grid" unselectable="on" ref="gridPanel" aria-rowcount="6" aria-colcount="3">
        <!--AG-HEADER-ROOT--><div class="ag-header ag-focus-managed ag-pivot-off" role="presentation" ref="headerRoot" unselectable="on" style="height: 26px; min-height: 26px;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedLeftHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
            <div class="ag-header-viewport" ref="eHeaderViewport" role="presentation">
                <div class="ag-header-container" ref="eHeaderContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: 300px; transform: translateX(0px);"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 300px;"><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="1" col-id="lookupCode" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-220-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Material</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="2" col-id="description" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-223-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Description</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="3" col-id="projectLookupCode" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-226-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Project</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedRightHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-top" ref="eTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eLeftTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-viewport" ref="eTopViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-top-container" ref="eTopContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 300px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eRightTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eTopFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal ag-row-no-animation" ref="eBodyViewport" role="presentation">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eLeftContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 250px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="228" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="232" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="236" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="3" aria-rowindex="5" row-id="3" comp-id="240" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(150px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="4" aria-rowindex="6" row-id="4" comp-id="244" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(200px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-center-cols-clipper" ref="eCenterColsClipper" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 250px;">
                <div class="ag-center-cols-viewport" ref="eCenterViewport" role="presentation" style="height: calc(100% + 17px);">
                    <div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="228" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="229" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="230" col-id="description" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="231" col-id="projectLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">Derek Project</div></div><div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="232" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="233" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="234" col-id="description" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="235" col-id="projectLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">Derek Project 7</div></div><div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="236" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="237" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="238" col-id="description" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">A single blue pillow</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="239" col-id="projectLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">ST P&amp;S</div></div><div role="row" row-index="3" aria-rowindex="5" row-id="3" comp-id="240" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(150px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="241" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">12</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="242" col-id="description" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">XtraRainbowSheet</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="243" col-id="projectLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">ST P&amp;S</div></div><div role="row" row-index="4" aria-rowindex="6" row-id="4" comp-id="244" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(200px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="245" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 0px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" comp-id="246" col-id="description" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 100px;">1</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" comp-id="247" col-id="projectLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 100px; left: 200px;">002</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eRightContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 250px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="0" comp-id="228" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="1" aria-rowindex="3" row-id="1" comp-id="232" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(50px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="2" aria-rowindex="4" row-id="2" comp-id="236" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(100px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="3" aria-rowindex="5" row-id="3" comp-id="240" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(150px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div><div role="row" row-index="4" aria-rowindex="6" row-id="4" comp-id="244" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-last" aria-selected="false" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(200px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to select this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-full-width-container" ref="eFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 250px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-bottom" ref="eBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eLeftBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-viewport" ref="eBottomViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-bottom-container" ref="eBottomContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 300px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eRightBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eBottomFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll" ref="eHorizontalScrollBody" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
            <div class="ag-horizontal-left-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalLeftSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollViewport" style="height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;">
                <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-container" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 17px; max-height: 17px; min-height: 17px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-horizontal-right-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalRightSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--AG-OVERLAY-WRAPPER--><div class="ag-overlay ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true" ref="overlayWrapper">
            <div class="ag-overlay-panel">
                <div class="ag-overlay-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper" ref="eOverlayWrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    
                <div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-bottom" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div></div>
                
                <!--AG-PAGINATION--><div class="ag-paging-panel ag-unselectable ag-hidden" id="ag-185" aria-live="polite" aria-describedby="ag-185-start-page ag-185-start-page-number ag-185-of-page ag-185-of-page-number ag-185-first-row ag-185-to ag-185-last-row ag-185-of ag-185-row-count">
                <span class="ag-paging-row-summary-panel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <span id="ag-185-first-row" ref="lbFirstRowOnPage" class="ag-paging-row-summary-panel-number"></span>
                    <span id="ag-185-to">to</span>
                    <span id="ag-185-last-row" ref="lbLastRowOnPage" class="ag-paging-row-summary-panel-number"></span>
                    <span id="ag-185-of">of</span>
                    <span id="ag-185-row-count" ref="lbRecordCount" class="ag-paging-row-summary-panel-number"></span>
                </span>
                <span class="ag-paging-page-summary-panel" role="presentation">
                    <div ref="btFirst" class="ag-paging-button" role="button" aria-label="First Page" tabindex="0"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-first" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></div>
                    <div ref="btPrevious" class="ag-paging-button" role="button" aria-label="Previous Page" tabindex="0"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-previous" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></div>
                    <span class="ag-paging-description" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span id="ag-185-start-page">Page</span>
                        <span id="ag-185-start-page-number" ref="lbCurrent" class="ag-paging-number"></span>
                        <span id="ag-185-of-page">of</span>
                        <span id="ag-185-of-page-number" ref="lbTotal" class="ag-paging-number"></span>
                    </span>
                    <div ref="btNext" class="ag-paging-button" role="button" aria-label="Next Page" tabindex="0"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-next" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></div>
                    <div ref="btLast" class="ag-paging-button" role="button" aria-label="Last Page" tabindex="0"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-last" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></div>
                </span>
            </div>
                
            </div></ag-grid-angular></mobileweb-mobile-grid></div></div>
```

I tried to use this code to find all elements and click on the text if the text value is found:

```
        WebElement tableContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("table-container"));

        List<WebElement> list = tableContainer.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));

        // iterate sub-elements
        for ( WebElement element : list )
        {
            System.out.println("Searching for " + element.getText());

            if(element.getText().equals(valueToSelect))
            {
                element.click();
                break; 
            }
        }

        .....
        // Click Confirm button to submit form
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        System.out.println("Click on Button " + name + " using id locator " + button_id);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(button_id)));
        webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

But it's not working. Table row is not selected. Text values are printed during execution but nothing is selected. Can you advice me how I can implement the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XPATH selector to find an element by it's text. You can then `.click()` that element if it is clickable.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text=()='foo']");`

Reads like: `//` starting anywhere on the page `*` any tagName `[text()='foo']` whose text is 'foo'

Comment: Can you extend the example a little bit please? I can't make it working.